# When updating DNS entries should I also update them at the domain registrar?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registrar

I am wondering specifically about MX entries. I use whois.com for my registrar and there is a DNS manager there I can add entries to. I have a VPS and can modify a DNS zone there as well. Which should I do? Both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should change your entries only on your master server (not secondary).

The DNS is based on *delegation*: you do what you want in your zone, without a need to explicitely tell to anyone.